# Estimating the force needed to increase height of a mountain?

Tags: forces, geophysics

How would you estimate the force required by a tectonic plate to make the height of a mountain increase when it pushes against another?
I've used a method to try and do it for Mt Everest and have ended up with 8x10^(-7)N required to increase its height which I don't think sounds reasonable

By the way, I was doing this for fun (it doesn't have any real life value, I don't think)

Comment: Use the Force of gravity, Luke! F=m*g. m is the mass of your mountain and g is Earth's gravitational surface acceleration.

Comment: After a point the height of a mountain cannot increase anymore lest it will collapse on its own weight. This is somehow analogous to the fact that scale-invariance is no that invariant (or in other words there are many concepts of scale involved and scale-invariance does not apply to all). There is an argument that a horse scaled down by e.g 0.5 will NOT have the strength scaled by same (or analogous) amount and so on

Answer (score 1):

When tectonic plates collide, the crust can become *thicker* at the edge of collision by the folding and faulting of crustal rocks. Because crust has a lower density than the asthenosphere and mantle, the region of thicker crust can rise due to *buoyancy forces* until it reaches isostatic equilibrium. This model of orogeny is referred to in geology as [isostasy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isostasy).

Therefore the "force acting to increase the height of a mountain" you wish to estimate is the buoyant force on the mountain/root system. And it will go to zero approaching equilibrium. Use dimensional analysis to write down an equation for static equilibrium:

[mountain weight force]-[buoyant force] = 0

m(h+H)Ag - MHAg = 0

Where m and M are the mass density of the crust and mantle respectively. Where h and H are the mountain's height and the mountain-root's depth respectively. The horizontal cross-section area of the mountain is A. The gravitational acceleration is g.

Think about this and you'll see how it may explain how erosion of mountain-tops has caused the uplift of the Cascades, whereas eruption of seafloor basalts has led to the sinking of the Hawaiian islands.

Answer (score 0):

In really simple terms the equation f=mg can be utilised. It calculates the gravitational potential energy of the mountain and therefore the energy needed to lift a mountain.